# Can I change favicon without modifying the master page?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

I am trying to change the favicon for a site in SharePoint Online. I have seen how it is possible to do this by modifying a master page. However, with SharePoint Online Microsoft was recommended *not* modifying master pages as it might (will) break things when they push automatic updates- or it may just prevent auto updates, I'm not sure which, but either scenario I want to avoid.

Is this possible?  Is there a file I can just replace somewhere on SharePoint Online?  Could someone show me that path, if so?

Answer (score 0):

It is highly unlikely, that you will break something by replacing the path to the favicon in your master page.
In addition, it don't believe there is a way without laying hand on your master page file.

So it is back to basics I'm afraid

1. Upload your custom favicon.ico file
2. Make a copy of your master page file.
3. Edit that copy and replace the path to the favicon.ico
4. Save & publish

Comment: I'm fine with doing that - but does having a custom master page literally disable the ability for auto upgrades, which is kind of the point of share point online...?

Comment: Once you change the path or the favicon, even if MS upgrades, it won't change:
 <SharePoint:SPShortcutIcon runat="server" IconUrl="/_layouts/15/images/favicon.ico?rev=46" /> -->  <SharePoint:SPShortcutIcon runat="server" IconUrl="/yourPath/favicon.ico" />

Answer (score 0):

In 2013, with server access you can just replace the 'favicon.ico' file in the _layouts/15/images/favicon.ico  But I don't think there is a way without modifying the master page in SharePoint Online.

Answer (score 0):

The another option of changing the favicon icon without modifying master page is using jQuery.

Upload your favicon icon in SharePoint and use below jQuery code to replace this on run time:

```
$("link[rel='shortcut icon']").attr("href","[Favicon Icon URL]");
```

Hope this will help you meet your requirement.